# Qual é a finalidade do método mágico __clone?

Tags: php, método, clone

No PHP temos o método mágico `__clone`. Ele serve para definir um comportamento quando você clona um objeto, através da palavra chave `clone`.

Até aí tudo bem. Porém não entendi muito bem por que ter esse método mágico, já que a palavra `clone` por se só já clona um objeto.

Exemplo 1:

```
 $a = new ArrayObject(['nome' => 'Wallace']);

 $b = clone $a;
```

Outro detalha que eu queria entender é que eu já vi algumas bibliotecas em PHP usarem esse método mágico para operações parecidas com essa abaixo:

Exemplo 2:

```
  class X {
       public function __construct (Y $y) {
          $this->y = $y;
       }

       public function __clone() {
          $this->y = clone $this->y;
       }
  }
```

Baseando-se nas observações acima, pergunto:

- Existe algum caso onde é, realmente, necessário definir um comportamento para a clonagem de um objeto?
- Por que algumas bibliotecas utilizam `__clone` para clonar uma propriedade correspondente à uma instância de um objeto (como no exemplo 2)?

Comment: Mas ele é mágico mesmo?

Comment: Sim, ele é Mágico, Mágico

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YkZbv.jpg

Comment: Ele também serve para privar a sua classe de ser clonada. Quando você torna o método 'private'. É muito utilizado em design pattern de padrão do tipo singleton.

Comment: @IvanFerrer boa observação, isso é bom.

Comment: http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=205960&type=card

Comment: Esse é um método que nunca entendi pra que serve efetivamente

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Deep clone

Porque a clonagem, em geral, envolve copiar todo o conteúdo do objeto de forma profunda (*deep*). Ou seja, copia também os objetos referenciados dentro desse objeto. Eventualmente pode-se querer até que toda árvore de objetos seja clonada, se for possível (os objetos referenciados precisam ser capazes de serem clonados profundamente).

Como a maneira de copiar esses objetos pode variar bastante, você tem que escrever o código que vai fazer isto. Isso ocorre muito quando você segura recursos externos na classe, como arquivos e objetos GUI, mas não se limita a estas coisas. Qualquer coisa que precise de independência total dos dados precisa de uma clonagem profunda.

## Shallow clone

Se não criar esse método o PHP irá clonar de forma rasa (*shallow*), ou seja, copiará só o objeto, seus membros por referência terão apenas as referências copiadas que apontará para o mesmo objeto que seu objeto original apontava. Isso pode ser o que deseja em alguns casos, mas não em todos.

Aí muita gente começa se perder criando classes. A maioria dos programadores não entendem todas implicações de se criar um classe. Costuma dar certo porque em geral as classes não fazem nada sofisticado, ou mesmo elas nem eram necessárias de fato. Na verdade só não dá um monte de problema porque os códigos PHP são o que eu sempre falo, apenas *scripts* simples. Se fossem aplicações complexas de fato muita classes começaria explodir. Em geral seu uso é muito contido e clonagens profundas não costumam ser necessárias. Onde elas são necessárias costuma ser escritas por programadores que possuem mais noção do funcionamento da computação como um todo.

## Clonar != Copiar

Note que clonar, mesmo a rasa, é diferente de copiar o objeto, a cópia pura só copia a referência do objeto, e não o objeto.

## Exemplos

No exemplo da pergunta `$b` terá um objeto igualzinho a `$a`, mas será outro objeto. Eles serão completamente independentes, cada um com sua vida própria, mudar um não muda o outro. Você clonou e não simplesmente copiou. Se a clonagem será rasa ou profunda depende do tipo do objeto da variável `$a`. Até onde eu sei o `ArrayObject` não clona de forma profunda, pelo menos não tem nada que diga isto na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php).

Na classe `X` está fazendo isto com o seu membro, garantindo que uma cópia do membro seja feita e não só a referência.

```
$x = new X(new Y());
$y = clone $x;
```

Nesse caso já sabe que `$x` e `$y` serão independentes. Mas o mais importante é que internamente o membro `y`, acessado pelo `$this` também será independente em cada um dos objetos, ou seja, este membro será copiado também. Se não tivesse essa clonagem. Tanto `$x.y`, quanto `$y.y` apontariam para o mesmo objeto, e mudando em um, mudaria no outro, eles não seriam independentes. Provavelmente não era o que queria.

```
class A {
    public $b;
 
    public function __construct(B $b) {
        $this->b = $b;
    }
}
 
class B {}
 
class C extends A {
    public function __clone() {
        $this->b = clone $this->b;
    }
}
 
$a = new A(new B);
$aa = clone $a;
$b = $a;
$c = new C(new B);
$cc = clone $c;
echo "CÓPIA\n";
var_dump($a === $b); //é igual, ambos apontam para o mesmo objeto
var_dump($a->b === $b->b); //continua igual, é o mesmo objeto, não pode ser diferente
echo "SEM __CLONE\n";
var_dump($a === $aa); //é diferente, copiou o objeto
var_dump($a->b === $aa->b); //é igual, o membro continua sendo o mesmo objeto apontado
echo "COM __CLONE\n";
var_dump($c === $cc); //é diferente, copiou o objeto
var_dump($c->b === $cc->b); //é diferente, copiou o objeto referenciado pelo membro
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6shGQR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pekywldo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Clone.php).

O método mágico `__clone()` sempre é chamado pelo comando `clone` da linguagem, quando o método estiver disponível para aquele objeto, se não estiver disponível, a clonagem será rasa.

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

Answer (score 7):

## Sumário

Basicamente o método mágico `__clone()` serve como um "callback" após uma clonagem.

Quando um objeto é clonado o compilador busca pelo método mágico `__clone()` e, se existir é invocado.

## Instâncias independentes e atribuição por referência

Um objeto clonado é independente do original de onde foi clonado.

No entanto, você pode querer copiar ou fazer atribuições por referência dos membros do objeto original. Para isso existe o método mágico `__clone()` onde poderá realizar essas cópias.

O motivo de não ocorrer uma cópia profunda e completa de todo um objeto é que nem sempre se precisa de uma cópia profunda do objeto inteiro. Pelo menos não dentro da principal finalidade de uso que fazemos do PHP.

No manual do PHP tem exemplos suficientemente bons para compreender: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.cloning.php

## Sobre as duas questões no final

> Existe algum caso onde é, realmente, necessário definir um
> comportamento para a clonagem de um objeto?
>
> Por que algumas bibliotecas utilizam __clone para clonar uma propriedade
> correspondente à uma instância de um objeto (como no exemplo 2)?

É complicado tentar responder pois o motivo/razão/circunstância depende de um contexto.

Sem entender o contexto torna-se inviável responder.

Answer (score -5):

> Depois que a clonagem se completa, se um método __clone() estiver definido, o objeto recém criado terá seu método __clone() chamado, permitindo que qualquer propriedade seja alterada.
>
> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.cloning.php

Nothing more, nothing less.

```
// Force a copy of this->object, otherwise
// it will point to same object.
$this->object1 = clone $this->object1;
```

Comment: Não entendi o restante da resposta depois da parte tirada do Manual.

Comment: Achei que aqui era SO-PT...

Comment: Desculpem a sinceridade, mas esse +2 foi mal votado. Realmente, a resposta não explica nada, apenas faz uma referência ao manual (que por sua vez nunca explica nada direito).

Comment: A resposta é simplista e responde à pergunta feita no título da questão, mas ignora o conteúdo da pergunta, onde o AP já demonstra saber que a rotina é chamada e procura conhecer um caso de uso prático da mesma. Comparada com as demais ela é incompleta, porém ela foi dada antes, portanto não acho que mereça tantos negativos.