# Cópia de classe em C#

Tags: c#, c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Na programação em C++ para copiar uma classe, para outra, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
minhaClasse* class_1 = new minhaClasse();
minhaClasse* class_2 = new minhaClasse();
*class_2 = *class_1; // Faz a atribução membro-a-membro da classe
```

ou ainda

```
minhaClasse class_1; // declara a classe diretamente, e não um ponteiro
minhaClasse class_2;
class_2 = class_1; // Faz a atribuição membro-a-membro da classe
```

Enquanto que para copiar a referência, de uma classe para a referência de outra, fazemos o seguinte:

```
minhaClasse* class_1 = new minhaClasse();
minhaClasse* class_2;
class_2 = class_1; // Faz a a cópia da referência da classe 1 para a classe 2
```

ou ainda

```
minhaClasse class_1; // declara a classe diretamente, e não um ponteiro
minhaClasse* class_2;
class_2 = &class_1; // Faz a a cópia do referência da classe 1 para a classe 2
```

Pelo que tenho pesquisado de C#, só tem como copiar a referência de uma classe à outra, e não tem como fazer a copia membro a membro implicitamente (como no C++).

Isso é verdade?

Comment: Essa descrição usa o termo "referência" aplicado erradamente à linguagem C++. Onde está "referência" leia-se "ponteiro". Em C++ referência tem um outro significado técnico.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não é verdade exatamente. Claro que tem como, só é diferente.

## Solução pronta

Todo objeto em C# deriva da classe [`Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) que possui um método chamado [`MemberwiseClone()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Object_MemberwiseClone) que só pode ser acesso dentro da classe (é protegido). Ele faz a cópia rasa de todos os membros do objeto, como deseja.

Mas note que ele não faz a cópia profunda. Ou seja. Ele copia tudo o que está no objeto, bit a bit, mas não cria novos objetos para as referências desse objeto. Ele faz com os membros o mesmo que os últimos exemplos da pergunta. Ele copia as referências para o novo objeto, mas elas apontam para os mesmos objetos que o original apontam.

Então em uma cópia rasa o que modifica nesse objeto não afeta o objeto original, afinal eles são coisa bem distintas. Mas se modificar os objetos referenciados dentro do seu objeto essas modificações se refletirão no objeto original, já que a referência é a mesma nesses objetos.

Se está difícil entender isso precisa entender a [diferença entre tipos por valor e tipos por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101). E sobre [imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101).

Falo sobre isso em uma [pergunta de PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/138010/101). No geral é mais ou menos a mesma coisa.

Há um exemplo fazendo a cópia profunda na [documentação do `MemberwiseClone()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Object_MemberwiseClone).

## Solução personalizada

As classes que pretendem permitir que sejam copiadas precisam de um método `Clone()`. Isso é diferente do C++ que providencia um construtor de cópia sempre que o programador impeça explicitamente. A cópia é normal np C++. No C# é opção possível.

O método de clonagem só está disponível nas classes que implementam a interface [`IClonable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Nela você pode criar uma cópia rasa ou profunda. É decisão do programador decidir como a clonagem deve proceder. Cada classe deve decidir se deve fazer desta forma ou não, assim como no C++, mas no C++ se não criar nada personalizado, a cópia é rasa. No C# se deseja fazer só a cópia rasa simples precisa chamar o `MemberwiseClone()` dentro do `Clone()`, nada mais.

Quando usa a `IClonable` qualquer operação que exija uma clonagem pode receber esse objeto sem saber o que ele faz.

## Cópia profunda

É comum fazer a cópia profunda, mas nada obriga que seja assim. A documentação não determina o que o `Clone()` deve fazer. Pode fazer a cópia rasa, profunda, ou um meio termo. Sequer precisa fazer uma cópia rasa completa, pode ser apenas uma seleção de membros, se fizer sentido.

Se decidir fazer a cópia profunda o método `Clone()` deve criar novos objetos referenciados pelos membros e copiar seus conteúdos para a nova referência, provavelmente chamado o método `Clone()` de cada um deles. Ou seja, faz o que o AP fez nos primeiros exemplos da pergunta.

Se os objetos membros da sua classe possuem métodos `Clone()` que fazem cópia profunda, vai disparando a árvore de cópias. Torça para não ter referência cíclica e não acabar mais (tem solução, claro).

Claro que a clonagem não é a única opção, existem outras formas de copiar esses objetos. Uma opção, se disponível, é só criar um novo objeto passando os membros do original como argumentos no construtor, ou pode passar o objeto original como argumento. Há muita classe que faz isso. É uma forma de ter um construtor de cópia igual ao C++. Nesse construtor ele lê todos os membros e faz a cópia dos seus membros de forma adequada. Claro que quem for consumir isso, precisa saber que existe essa possibilidade, não é padronizada como a clonagem "oficial".

Algumas clonagens são bem complexas e podem ir muito além de só copiar memória.

É comum o pessoal ter um método de extensão que faz uma cópia profunda e implementa o método da interface implicitamente.

## Fora do padrão

Alguns objetos podem ter métodos específicos para fazer cópias de uma forma específica. Aí vai de cada um. Tem que ver a documentação da classe. Não pode ser usado de forma padronizada como o `MemberwiseClone()` e o `Clone()`. Um exemplo é o [`Array.Copy()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads). Também é comum implementar uma versão especializada do `Clone()` retornando o objeto do tipo da classe. A implementação de `IClonable` deve retornar um `object`, o que pode exigir um *cast* no seu uso.

Em tese é possível clonar até o que não está preparado para fazer isso. Mas é complicado. Tem que recorrer à reflexão para garantir que tudo o que é necessário será feito, tem que acessar coisas internas que são detalhes de implementação e nada garante que isso vá funcionar sempre.

A serialização é uma opção.

Note que não é tão comum o uso desta interface no C#. É raro o uso de cópia do conteúdo já que ela pode ser cara e e quase sempre não é a semântica desejada. Daí a existência de métodos mais específicos quando faz sentido. O próprio C++ tem preferido mover do que copiar.

## Conclusão

O tema é extenso, tema bastante coisa pra aprender sobre isso, tem muita situação problemática.

Fiz um exemplo com duas formas de clonagem.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/z4JNys). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OLYrck). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Clone.cs).

Comment: Entendi, o método `Clone()` não chama implicitamente o método `Clone()` dos objetos contidos na classe(como faz o C++ com o `map`, por exemplo, utilizando a sobrecarga do operador '=') ? Talvez seja uma pergunta um pouco idiota, mas já programo em C++ há muitos anos e sou um pouco acostumado demais.

Comment: Faz se você disser que deve fazer. O que o `Clone()` deve fazer é decisão do criador da classe. No exemplo do `map` foi decido fazer exatamente isso, falando em termos de C#, foi dado um clone nos seus membros. Você não vê isso. A chamada dos `Clone()` dos membros é feito dentro do `Clone()` desse objeto. Chamou ele, sai disparando todas clonagens necessárias. Mas tem caso que o criador da classe considera que isso não é adequado. Em tese você faz o que quiser dentro do `Clone()`. Mas em quase todos casos vai chamar o `MemberwiseClone()` em algum momento.

Comment: @bigown qual é a diferença de uma copia rasa e uma profunda? Isso me confundiu um pouco.

Comment: É difícil dizer isso em comentário. Mais ou menos é q que está no 3o. parágrafo que provavelmente não deu para entender. A cópia rasa é bit a bit do objeto. A profunda, vai disparando cópias dos objetos referenciados. Obviamente só faz isso com objetor de tipos por referência. Tipo por valor a cópia bit a bit é suficiente. Quando tem uma referência tem ou outro objeto em algum lugar, precisa copiar ele também, se copiar só o valor, ou seja, a referência, terá dois objetos com a mesma referência obviamente apontado para o mesmo objeto. O certo seria ter a criação de objeto novo. É o q deu aqui.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho coloquei um *link* na resposta para uma pergunta que eu respondi que talvez ajude.

Comment: Uma alternativa, para copiar a classe é _serializando_  em memória e depois _deserializar_, claro que isto vai gasta um pouco de recursos hehehe...

Comment: Engraçado como algo que deveria ser prático é complicado em linguagens como C# e Java. É especialmente difícil explicar a distinção entre uma referência e valor (em linguagens em que objetos são passados através de "cópia da referência" o cérebro de um programador acostumado a ter mais controle dói). Daí o pessoal começa a Serializar / Deserializar, escrever Frameworks para clonar objetos e coisas do gênero. Eu sinceramente acho que esse é um problema mal entendido e mal resolvido em Java. Pelo visto o C# segue a mesma linha.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly C# copiou boa parte dos defeitos do Java, principalmente deixando os objeto serem nulos por padrão. Mas na verdade é um problema complicado de resolver mesmo, não dá para ter regra única, mesmo o C++ tem problemas, apenas tem uma facilidade extra.

Comment: *Fair engough*. Para fazer justiça eu ainda acho que o C# acertou esse e outros assuntos um pouco melhor (por exemplo `ref` e `out` não existem em Java), nada como entrar alguns anos depois para fazer uma "cópia" aprimorada. Dito isso, ainda é assustador que ambas as linguagens não tenham métodos `shallowCopy` e `deepCopy` com possíveis variantes de estado (como o método `copy` em Scala. Você pode alterar qualquer parâmetro nomeado durante a cópia).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly eu acho isso um dos erros enormes do Java, em C# 7 estão ampliando o uso de `ref` de forma muito certa, e facilitando o uso do `out`, mais porque tem legado, porque estão criando tuplas na linguagem, que torna o `out` obsoleto. Parece que C# 7 melhora alguma coisa na cópia em alguma situação, mas ainda não me aprofundei. Java 10 resolve um dos problemas que C# arrumou, mas sem `ref` ele não poderá ser tão usado. Eu acho que o C# arrumou muita, mas ainda acho que uma nova linguagem com o que se sabe hoje seria útil (e se abandonar a sintaxe *C-like, melhor ainda).

Answer (score 4):

Por *default*, em C# se copia a referência e não o objeto. Mas você pode usar a *interface* `ICloneable` para fazer cópias da instância de objeto:

```
public class TestClass : ICloneable
{
    public String test;
    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Então, faça:

```
TestClass a = new TestClass();
TestClass b = (TestClass)a.Clone();
```