# Tipos iguais mas com objetos diferentes. Qual a melhor forma de usá-lo?

Tags: c#, .net, objetos, clone

Tive que criar um novo objeto mas totalmente igual ao existente no sistema C#. Já que os objetos são iguais tentei fazer:

```
ObjetoOriginal.Propriedades = ObjetoClone.Propriedades;
```

Infelizmente não funciona não é?

Tentei então:

```
ObjetoOriginal.Propriedades = (ObjetoOriginal)ObjetoClone.Propriedades;
```

E nada.

Então tive que fazer algo assim:

```
ObjetoOriginal.Propriedades.A = ObjetoClone.Propriedades.A;

ObjetoOriginal.Propriedades.B = ObjetoClone.Propriedades.B;
```

Qual seria a melhor forma para pegar todas as propriedades de uma vez?

Comment: Você tem controle sobre essa classe? Pode mexer nela?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro ponto: você deve pensar 10 vezes antes de clonar um objeto. Costuma ser problemático fazer isto e quase sempre não é necessário.

Se o objeto foi pensado para ser clonado ele implementará a interface [`IClonable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx). Eu [já respondi sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156883/101). E é recomendado fazer isso apenas onde é necessário e com muita consciência. É fácil fazer errado.

Me parece que está querendo clonar qualquer objeto. Se o objeto não foi pensado para ser clonado é quase certo que estará cometendo um erro, mas pode usar reflexão para fazer isso sem ter que ficar copiando cada membro manualmente. Idealmente crie um método para fazer isso de forma genérica:

```
static class ObjectUtil<T> {
    public static T Clone(T obj) {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var cloned = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++) {
            fields[i].SetValue(cloned, fields[i].GetValue(obj));
        }
        return (T)cloned;
    }   
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FoH79C). E [no **repl.it**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qpqcGq).  Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/CloneObject.cs).

Comment: Olá, Tivemos que clonar o objeto por causa de melhorias.
Estamos levando tudo o que há em certo projeto para outro.
Então durante execução eu preciso "recriar" o mesmo objeto com o novo tipo.
É algo assim meu cenário.
Enfim, da forma que eu fiz resolve este problema. Problema este que penso que não voltará a acontecer.

Mas irei testar o que mandou.
Abs

Comment: Esse é um caso que pode ser útil, mas faça com cuidado. Teste bem.

Answer (score 2):

Implemente a classe [ICloneable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) na sua classe que vai te proporcionar clonar uma cópia da classe com os mesmo valores, mas, sendo objetos distintos. Dentro do método criado pela implementação [ICloneable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) chame [MemberwiseClone()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) que retorna uma cópia em um novo objeto.

***Código:***

```
public class Propriedades: ICloneable
{
    public Propriedades()
    {

    }
    public int Id { get; set; } = 1;
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Name 1";

    public object Clone()
    {
        return MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

***Usar:***

```
Propriedades p = new Propriedades();
Propriedades c = (Propriedades)p.Clone(); //Clone "ICloneable"
```

---

Uma outra forma é utilizando [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13093/54880) ([reflection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13093/54880)):

```
Propriedades propr1 = new Propriedades();
propr1.Id = 2;
propr1.Name = "Nome 2";
Type propType1 = propr1.GetType();

Propriedades propr2 = new Propriedades();
Type propType2 = propr1.GetType();

foreach(PropertyInfo info in propType1.GetProperties())
{
    propType2.GetProperty(info.Name)
        .SetValue(propr2, info.GetValue(propr1));
}
```

o código acima pode ser simplificado com [métodos de extensão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136913/para-que-usar-m%C3%A9todos-de-extens%C3%A3o-do-c) com um código assim:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static T Clone<T>(this T _t)
        where T: class
    {
        T _r = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        Type _t1 = _t.GetType();
        Type _r1 = _r.GetType();
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info in _t1.GetProperties())
        {
            _r1.GetProperty(info.Name)
                .SetValue(_r, info.GetValue(_t));
        }
        return _r;
    }
}
```

e sua utilização é bem parecido com a primeira alternativa:

```
Propriedades propr1 = new Propriedades();
propr1.Id = 2;
propr1.Name = "Nome 2";


Propriedades propr2 = propr1.Clone(); // método de extensão
```

---

Tem também um pacote do [nuget](https://www.nuget.org) o [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), *exemplo*:

```
Propriedades propr1 = new Propriedades();
propr1.Id = 2;
propr1.Name = "Nome 2";


Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { });
Mapper.Configuration.CompileMappings();

Propriedades propr2 = Mapper.Map<Propriedades>(propr1);
```

---

<sub>***Observações:*** eu passaria os valores para as nova instâncias para não ter problema com *referencias* e *valores* inesperado. Só usaria se isso não comprometesse o código e suas instâncias, ainda o modo atribuição simples é o melhor jeito de implementar.</sub>

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [Interface ICloneable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Object.MemberwiseClone Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx)
- [How to Clone Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5359336/6797930)
- [O que é Reflection, por que é útil? Como usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13089/o-que-%C3%A9-reflection-por-que-%C3%A9-%C3%BAtil-como-usar)
- [Para que usar métodos de extensão do C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136913/para-que-usar-m%C3%A9todos-de-extens%C3%A3o-do-c)

Answer (score 2):

Venho aqui adicionar uma alternativa, que pode vir a ser útil caso a classe tenha uma referencia circular e você tenha domínio sobre a mesma.

Você pode decorar ela com o atributo [`[DataContract]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) e [`[DataMember]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) e seriaizar o binário da mesma usando o [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

segue o exemplo.:

```
var serialize = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
var myClone = default(MyClass);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    serialize.WriteObject(stream, myObject);
    stream.Position = 0;
    stream.Flush();
    myClone = (MyClass)serialize.ReadObject(stream);
}
```

Para que a serialização com referencias cíclicas dê certo, é necessario usar a propriade `IsReference` do `DataContrac` com valor igual à `true`;

Segue um exemplo completo.:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class Pessoa
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Pessoa Companheiro { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Pessoa Pai { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Pessoa Mae { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Pessoa> Filhos { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Pessoa> Irmaos { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pessoa1 = new Pessoa() { Nome = "Pai" };
            var pessoa2 = new Pessoa() { Nome = "Mãe" };
            var pessoa3 = new Pessoa() { Nome = "Filho 1" };
            var pessoa4 = new Pessoa() { Nome = "Filho 2" };
            var pessoa5 = new Pessoa() { Nome = "Filho 3" };

            pessoa1.Companheiro = pessoa2;
            pessoa2.Companheiro = pessoa1;
            pessoa1.Filhos = pessoa2.Filhos = new List<Pessoa> { pessoa3, pessoa4, pessoa5 };

            pessoa3.Pai = pessoa4.Pai = pessoa5.Pai = pessoa1;
            pessoa3.Mae = pessoa4.Mae = pessoa5.Mae = pessoa2;
            pessoa3.Irmaos = new List<Pessoa> { pessoa4, pessoa5 };
            pessoa4.Irmaos = new List<Pessoa> { pessoa3, pessoa5 };
            pessoa5.Irmaos = new List<Pessoa> { pessoa3, pessoa4 };

            var serialize = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Pessoa));
            var clone = default(Pessoa);
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serialize.WriteObject(stream, pessoa1);
                stream.Position = 0;
                stream.Flush();
                clone = (Pessoa)serialize.ReadObject(stream);
            }

            clone.Companheiro.Filhos[1].Nome = "Clone do Filho 2";
            Console.WriteLine($"{clone.Companheiro.Filhos[1].Nome}, {pessoa1.Companheiro.Filhos[1].Nome}, {pessoa4.Nome}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 gostei ......