# MemberwiseClone de agregados

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clone

Tenho em memória (ainda não foi armazenado em banco de dados) um um objeto do tipo `List<NotaFiscal>`. Preciso passar um item dessa lista como parâmetro para uma tela, para que seja feita alterações  nesse objeto. Porém pode ser necessário que o usuário cancele as alterações, e objeto volte ao seu estado original.

Então, ao abrir a tela que irá receber esse objeto de `NotaFiscal`, eu faço um clone desse objeto usando `MemberwiseClone()`.

Classe **NotaFiscal**

```
public class NotaFiscal
{
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string Serie { get; set; }
    .........
    public ICollection<NotaFiscalProduto> Produtos { get; set; }

     public NotaFiscal Clone()
     {
        return (NotaFiscal) MemberwiseClone();
     }
}
```

Classe **TelaNotaFiscal**

```
public partial class TelaNotaFiscal: Window
{
     private readonly NotaFiscal _notaBackup;
     private readonly NotaFiscal _nota;
     private bool _cancelarAlteracao;

     public NotaFiscal Nota => !_cancelarAlteracao ? _nota : _notaBackup;

     public TelaNotaFiscal(NotaFiscal nota)
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         _notaBackup = nota.Clone();
         _nota = nota;
     }
 }
```

Classe **TelaFatura**

```
 private void btnNf_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    var botao = (Button)sender;
    var nota = (NotaFiscal)botao.DataContext;
    var telaNota = new TelaNotaFiscal(nota);
    telaNota.Closed += (sen, es) =>
    {
       nota = telaNota.Nota;
     };
     telaNota .ShowDialog();
  }
```

Se o usuário cancelar a alteração, as propriedades `Numero` e `Serie` voltam ao valor anterior. Porém, se for removido itens de `_nota.Produtos`, isso também é refletido em `_notaBackup.Produtos`

**Imediate Window**

Analisando o Imediate posso concluir que os objetos `_nota` e `_notaBackup` são diferentes, porém as posições zero de `Produtos` são objetos iguais.

> _nota.Produtos[0].GetHashCode()
>
> 45644990
>
> _notaBackup.Produtos[0].GetHashCode()
>
> 45644990
>
> _nota.GetHashCode()
>
> 59505294
>
> _notaBackup.GetHashCode()
>
> 23797978

O que poderia fazer para corrigir esse problema? Ou qual outra alternativa para editar esse objeto em memória e reverter as alterações se necessário.

Comment: Acho que o `GetHashCode()` não faz o que você imagina. Objetos diferentes com valores iguais terão o mesmo *hashcode*.

Comment: Não sabia disso. "Achei" quera uma espécie de identificador único do objeto. Obrigado

Comment: O identificador único do objeto é o próprio objeto e ele só vale sob certas circunstâncias.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184019/o-que-%C3%A9-hashcode-e-qual-sua-finalidade/184034#184034

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precisa fazer uma cópia profunda. Já [falei sobre isto em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156883/101).

Não é fácil fazer isto da forma correta. O mais simples e seguro é fazer uma serialização e desserialização do objeto. <strike>Hoje quase todo mundo usam [NewtonSoft JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) para isto</strike>. Na verdade agora tem o [`System.Text.Json`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-5.0?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é a maior preferência por várias razões, ainda que ele não seja tão poderoso, não consegue lidar com todas situações, mas com quase todas.

Faz algo assim:

```
public NotaFiscal Clone() {
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null)) {
        return default(NotaFiscal);
    }
    var deserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace};
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotaFiscal>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this), deserializeSettings);

 }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/DeepClone.cs).

Obviamente pode fazer isto como um método utilitário ou de extensão também. Fiz do jeito que começou.

Se algo não for serializável você pode ter problemas. A solução provavelmente passa por usar [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154462/101) e copiar todos campos de todo o grafo de objetos. Tarefa nada simples e nem vou me meter nisso.

Comment: Não tinha pensando em serialização. Vou tentar e ver se atende.

Comment: Fazendo a cópia com serialização deu certo! Obrigado