# Existe diferença de performance entre o "new" e o "clone" no PHP?

Tags: php, desempenho, característica-linguagem

Qual a vantagem de utilizar o `clone` em vez do `new` para criar um objeto no PHP?

Sei que para utilizar o `clone` é necessário passar um objeto instanciado. Mas por não ser necessário "refazer" a instância há ganho significativo de performance?

Preciso criar muitos objetos de uma vez e penso em usar o `clone` para ganhar performance, se for o caso, por a performance ser ruim usando o `new`.

Comment: relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138003/qual-%C3%A9-a-finalidade-do-m%C3%A9todo-m%C3%A1gico-clone

Comment: O importante é a finalidade de cada um, e não velocidade. Tem que usar clone quando quer clonar, e new quando quiser uma instância nova. Não são funções substitutas. O clone vai ter que copiar a vtable incluindo todos os valores, o new vai chamar o construtor. Como já muito bem respondido pelo @maniero, não importa qual é a menos ou mais performática, pq isso é irrelevante no contexto. Até pq se está usando PHP e quer performance, usar OOP já é o primeiro erro. OOP não traz benefico em PHP e gera um custo absurdo, ainda mais que é uma linguagem de script, que por natureza não mantem estado.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Não importa. Por duas razões.

## PHP é uma linguagem de *script*

Então se a performance é importante, a linguagem é errada. Você terá um ganho absurdamente maior do que se preocupar com isso. Como diz o Donald Knuth:

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil
>
> Devemos esquecer pequenas ineficiências em 97% do tempo: otimização prematura é a raiz de todos os males.

Esse é um caso clássico que o resto que está à volta consome muito mais tempo e isto não fará diferença significativa. Especialmente em um Singleton que não executará várias vezes (e nem entrei no mérito que Singleton em PHP é um canhão pra matar passarinho, ou seja, criar uma arquitetura mais simples dará uma performance muito melhor que se preocupar com isso). PHP é extremamente ineficiente.

E já vi PHP ter absurdas diferenças de performance de uma versão para outra, e sem critério, então o que pode ser válido um dia pode não ser no outro.

[Fizeram um teste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18040351/221800), mas relutei um postar porque sei como o cérebro humano funciona e irá considerá-lo como algo útil, quando na verdade ele não é. Note que usa uma versão antiga, não sabemos as condições exatas e foi muito mal medido já que o custo de iniciar e parar o relógio tantas vezes deve estar interferindo muito mais no resultado. Quase todos os testes de *benchmark* que já vi sendo feitos em PHP são errados.

## Semântica diferente

O segundo motivo é que eles fazem coisas bem diferentes. Quase sempre clonar algo é um erro e tem implicações que poucas pessoas dominam. Existe uma semântica específica de como o objeto será copiado que nem sempre é óbvia. Então criar um novo objeto do jeito que você está vendo ali no código costuma ser a solução. O maior problema de clonar algo, e até saber qual é o mais lento, é porque talvez ele faça coisas que você nem espera que ele faça, e estaríamos comparando maçãs com laranjas.

Na verdade mesmo isso pode se tornar um problema. Sem falar que ter esses objetos pode ser uma complicação desnecessária, mas isto é outro assunto.

Chega a ser até complicado medir com precisão em PHP, e os resultados costumam ser inconsistentes e medir outras coisas que não este ponto específico.

E há uma premissa errada na pergunta. O `clone` "refaz" a instância sim. Ele cria um novo objeto e faz uma cópia.

## Seu caso de baixa performance

Muito provavelmente a performance ruim vem de outro ponto e motivo. Só comece a pensar em melhorar a performance de algo quando puder provar que é aquilo que está causando a perda.

Novamente, simplifique seu código e arquitetura, entenda o que está fazendo e meça adequadamente. Se nada disso resolver, e deveria, aí troque de linguagem. Mas trocar a linguagem e não resolver esses outros problemas vai ajudar bem pouco.

Faça testes de PHP com uma linguagem mais rápida. Se o teste for feito de forma adequada nas coisas certas verá uma absurda diferença. Embora PHP atenda certos problemas, quando a performance é o mais importante, ela é inadequada, isso é mensurável, não é questão de opinião.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta que deve fazer a si mesmo é, se é necessário instanciar tantas classes. Modificar para `clone()` não trará vantagem visível pois seria uma microotimização e sem garantia de que seria 0.01s mais rápido.

Nos testes que encontram-se por aí é normalmente feito em modo CLI com 100 mil iterações. Na prática mesmo, o PHP vai rodar como fcgi ou módulo do apache, etc, onde o resultado será variado conforme o ambiente e rodando 1 iteração na maioria das vezes.
Em suma é uma total perda de tempo pensar nesse tipo de otimização. Talvez uma remodelagem da lógica possa trazer algo eficaz. Eu já fiz remodelagens que melhoraram 550% e outros 1500% a performance e em nenhuma delas me preocupei com microotimizações. Foi puramente remodelagem. Muitas vezes a troca de ambiente já traz uma vantagem significativa, por exemplo, se está em módulo do apache, mudar para fcgi no nginx. Enfim, não existe mágica e não estou dizendo que fcgi no nginx é o pica das galáxias. Pode ser uma roubada também. Foi um mero exemplo.

Programo em C# também e por vezes uso PHP para resolver certas coisas onde o C# é "pior" e vice-versa. Não existe uma mágica onde um só resolve tudo. Uso muito JAVA também para resolver certas coisas que no PHP ficaria mais lento ou inconveniente. Então apenas invoco um executável JAVA ou de outra linguagem dentro do PHP.

Quer outro exemplo? Abre uma TV da Sony. Você vai encontrar dentro dela, componentes de concorrentes como sharp, panasonic, toshiba, LG. Daí você se pergunta "isso é uma TV da sony?"
Enfim, não importa que tecnologia usa. O que importa é o resultado final.

Considere uma otimização da arquitetura e **uso estratégico de diversas tecnologias** de forma inteligente, pensando também no modelo de negócios ($$), do que em microotimizações pontuais ou questões ideológicas e gostos pessoais. Aliás, nem dá para considerar microotimizações como essa que perguntou sobre New() vs Clone().
Ou pior ainda, radicalizações insanas como "não presta, troca tudo mimimi php mimimi", que provavelmente vai ouvir por aí e não resolve nada.

Sendo bem objetivo:

- Planeje a otimização da arquitetura como um todo fazendo remodelagens.
- O plano deve considerar o modelo de negócios Por exemplo, quanto a brincadeira vai custar a sua empresa ou ao seu patrão/cliente?
- Alcançar um resultado satisfatório de forma racional, econômica e rápida.