# Qual é o propósito da serialização?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, serialização

Qual é o propósito da serialização de objetos?

Comment: Olá, da uma olhada neste [artigo](https://www.devmedia.com.br/serializacao-de-objetos-em-java/23413)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

[De acordo com a resposta em inglês:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization)

Serialização de objetos é a conversão de um objeto para uma série de bytes, de forma que este objeto possa ser facilmente salvo em um dispositivo de armazenamento ou transmitido através uma via de comunicação. A transmissão de bytes pode então ser des-serializada, isto é, convertida novamente em uma réplica do objeto original.

Answer (score 1):

O que é serialização, se fosse que queria perguntar seria duplicata: [O que é serialização? Quando usar? Como implementar no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13087/101).

Respondendo o que perguntou:

Serialização é usada para trabalhar o objeto em uma forma simples e agnóstica, em geral para ser transportada de um lugar para outro (seja um armazenamento em banco de dados, comunicação entre processos e máquinas envolvidas em uma aplicação que precisam ter o objeto copiado, cache, ou mesmo a cópia do objeto no mesmo processo de forma [profunda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138003/101) ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156883/101)), ou ainda pra um ser humano poder ler, entre outros motivos).

Em geral isto é feito como um texto assim não tem especificidades de plataforma e de tecnologia usada, mas ao contrário do que as pessoas acham é possível ser binário, que costuma ser mais eficiente.

O objeto na memória tem uma forma, uma organização que é própria da plataforma e tecnologia usada, que seja o mais otimizado para aquilo, o que provavelmente não bate com outras tecnologias, ou até essas outras encontram dificuldade pra se adaptar. E quando falo em tecnologia falo de versão da mesma. Uma versão diferente pode ter uma organização diferente. O formato interno é detalho de implementação, não é confiável para uso. A serialização sempre usa uma forma **estável**, mesmo que não otimizada.